# How is the commitment for a previous outpoint computed (tx v2)?

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-hash

I've been working on a Go-based Monero library and for the MixRing of a RCT, we need the previous outpoints that are being mixed in. It's easy enough to grab those output keys and put them in the destination. The mask, however, is computed with the commitment. What commitment is that referring to? How do I compute it?

Pointers to code in the monero-project/monero codebase would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

There is an outPk for each output in a transaction, and therefore you'll need the outPks from the transactions that created each of the inputs. (Where each outPk is C, i.e. the sum of Ci).

OutPks are stored after the pseudoOuts and ecdhInfos in every version 2 transaction.